# CAS Apereo with OAuth2: How to release Client-ID in Userprofile

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, cas

I want to output the Client-ID in the CAS Profile URI (/cas/oauth2.0/profile). Is this possible? If yes, where can I enable this behavior?

Currently the output looks like this:

```
{
  "attributes": { ... }
  "id": "<username>"
}
```

I would like to look like this:

```
{
  "attributes": { ... }
  "id": "<username>"
  "client_id": "<client-id of application>"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

CAS Version: 5.2.0

Comment: Please specify the CAS server version: https://apereo.github.io/cas/Mailing-Lists.html#data-data-data

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you ask is already present. You may need to switch to the latest 5.2.x line to test and confirm

Comment: Ok, thank you, it appeared now (without upgrade?) - I don't know how and why ^^